# Luatex and \diagup or \diagdown

Tags: symbols, luatex, packages

For some reason, it seems `\diagup` and `\diagdown` are not provided by `unicode-math` or `amsfonts` when those are called by Luatex. Here's a minimal (non)working example:

```
% Intended LaTeX compiler: lualatex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{lualatex-math}


\begin{document}

$\diagup$

\end{document}
```

I found those symbols not working anymore in an old document that I wrote before switching to Luatex without any special sources for them. They seem to be provided by the `mathabx` package, but that conflicts with `unicode-math`. I also tried using

```
\RequirePackage{libertinus}
\setmathfont{STIX Math}
```

because I found `diagup` among the stix-symbols in the Comprehensive Latex Symbol List, but it didn't work either. What's up with that? And what's the best way to get those symbols again?

Comment: this was a bug, fixed at source, see https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/pull/604#issuecomment-1675742185

Comment: don't load amsfonts and unicode-math at same time though (that is not the cause of the problem but will cause other issues)